# how to delete tastypie model resource index

Tags: python, django, api, tastypie

I'm implementing a rest api using django-tastypie. My api resource is defined as follows:

```
class AddressResource(ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        resource_name = 'address'
        queryset = Address.objects.all()
        always_return_data = True
        authorization = Authorization()
        serializer = Serializer(formats=['json'])

        validation = Validation()
```

I have a model Address defined as:

```
class Address(models.Model):
    number = models.IntegerField()
    street = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    postalCode = models.CharField(max_length=5)
```

I can create Address resources posting to the url http://mydomain.com/api/v1/Address/. After Address resource creation the resource uri is /api/v1/Address/1/..../api/v1/Address/2/....etc

If I delete the resources directly from the model database or by doing a HTTP DELETE of the resource http://mydomain.com/api/v1/Address/2/, when I do a new post of a resource the id of the resource uri is still incrementing based on the last index.

Example: I have 30 address resources and I delete all of them, when I do a new post of a new resource the resource uri is /api/v1/Address/31/ instead of 1.

How can I delete the index when a resource is deleted?

Thanks in advance
Victor

Answer (score 0):

Thats not possible if you are using autoincrement field, which is default primare key field for django. To do what you want you need to specify you own field for primare key using primary_key=True attribute. And you will need to set it to what you want manually when you create a new model instance.